# Azure AD Identity issuer MicrosoftAccount

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In our tenant my user has multiple identity issuers. Other users have just one. In case of my user there is an issuer that is the same what other users have and there is an issuer named MicrosoftAccount. In case of the MicrosoftAccount issuer the Sign-in type is federated.

What does this mean? Why it is added to my account? What advantages it has and can I add it for other users too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Identity Issuer** with a value of **Multiple** states that the user has multiple issuers. You can get the details of the issuers **(Identity Issuer)** as well as a few other information like **Sign-In Type** and the **Issuer Assigned ID** once you click on that "**Multiple**" hyperlink under the **Identity Issuer** column.

What I have observe is there is basically three identity issuers.

1. ***{TennantName}.onmicrosoft.com***
2. ***ExternalAzureAD***
3. ***MicrosoftAccount***

[image]

•   **`{TennantName}.onmicrosoft.com`**: we get this identity issuer when we add any member to Azure AD.

•   **`ExternalAzureAD`** : This identity issuer we get when we  federate a user from one tenant to another tenant. Its user type is guest users.

•   **`MicrosoftAccount`**: This identity user we get when we send invite to any user (any email it could be) and it should be accepting the invitation from user side.

So based on above explanation your account `identity issuer` is `Microsoft Account` so you should be `guest user` and you already accept the `invitation`.

Suppose If you are not accepting `invitation`, it should only shows **`{TennantName}.onmicrosoft.com`** `identity issuer` in the portal.

[image]

In the above screen shot `Rahul Shaw` `identity issuer` was showing only  **`M3XXXX7257.onmicrosoft.com`** once I have accept inivitation it showing `**Microsoft Account**` as well.